# How protect dbt seed command from running in production?

Tags: airflow, dbt

There is a [seed](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/commands/seed) command in dbt. It allows the insertion of data from csv files into the database. But if I run this on production I will corrupt production data. So is there any protection mechanism to ensure that seed command will not be run on production?

For example can dbt check that target table is not empty and run seeds only when this is true?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but one possible solution is to use `dbt seed` as normal and then use a static materialization off the seed model into an intermediary model, which will then be safe from being updated.

Say your seed file is `my_seed.csv` and your downstream models are currently using `ref('my_seed')`.

First, create a macro for static materialization (this is just a modified version of the `table` materialization that checks for existence first):

```
{% materialization static, default -%}
  {# relations #}
  {%- set existing_relation = load_cached_relation(this) -%}
  {%- set target_relation = this.incorporate(type='table') -%}
  {%- set temp_relation = make_temp_relation(target_relation)-%}
  {%- set intermediate_relation = make_intermediate_relation(target_relation)-%}
  {%- set backup_relation_type = 'table' if existing_relation is none else existing_relation.type -%}
  {%- set backup_relation = make_backup_relation(target_relation, backup_relation_type) -%}

  {# configs #}
  {%- set unique_key = config.get('unique_key') -%}
  {%- set full_refresh_mode = (should_full_refresh()  or existing_relation.is_view) -%}
  {%- set on_schema_change = incremental_validate_on_schema_change(config.get('on_schema_change'), default='ignore') -%}

  {# 
    the temp_ and backup_ relations should not already exist in the database; get_relation
    will return None in that case. Otherwise, we get a relation that we can drop
    later, before we try to use this name for the current operation. This has to happen before
    BEGIN, in a separate transaction
  #}
  {%- set preexisting_intermediate_relation = load_cached_relation(intermediate_relation)-%}
  {%- set preexisting_backup_relation = load_cached_relation(backup_relation) -%}
  {# grab current tables grants config for comparision later on #}
  {% set grant_config = config.get('grants') %}
  {{ drop_relation_if_exists(preexisting_intermediate_relation) }}
  {{ drop_relation_if_exists(preexisting_backup_relation) }}

  {{ run_hooks(pre_hooks, inside_transaction=False) }}

  {# `BEGIN` happens here: #}
  {{ run_hooks(pre_hooks, inside_transaction=True) }}

  {% set to_drop = [] %}

  {% if existing_relation is none %}
      {% set build_sql = get_create_table_as_sql(False, target_relation, sql) %}
  {% else %}
    {% set build_sql = "select 1" %}
  {% endif %}

  {% call statement("main") %}
      {{ build_sql }}
  {% endcall %}

  {% if need_swap %}
      {% do adapter.rename_relation(target_relation, backup_relation) %}
      {% do adapter.rename_relation(intermediate_relation, target_relation) %}
      {% do to_drop.append(backup_relation) %}
  {% endif %}

  {% set should_revoke = should_revoke(existing_relation, full_refresh_mode) %}
  {% do apply_grants(target_relation, grant_config, should_revoke=should_revoke) %}

  {% do persist_docs(target_relation, model) %}

  {% if existing_relation is none or existing_relation.is_view or should_full_refresh() %}
    {% do create_indexes(target_relation) %}
  {% endif %}

  {{ run_hooks(post_hooks, inside_transaction=True) }}

  {# `COMMIT` happens here #}
  {% do adapter.commit() %}

  {% for rel in to_drop %}
      {% do adapter.drop_relation(rel) %}
  {% endfor %}

  {{ run_hooks(post_hooks, inside_transaction=False) }}

  {{ return({'relations': [target_relation]}) }}
{%- endmaterialization %}
```

Then, create a model called `my_seed_static.sql` using the static materialization:

```
{{
  config({
    "materialized": 'static',
  })
}}

SELECT * FROM {{ ref('my_seed') }}
```

Then update your downstream models to use `ref('my_seed_static')`. When `dbt seed` is run, it WILL update your seed table. But, `my_seed_static` will not change unless the table doesn't exist.