# In Data Build Tool (DBT) - a model that is disabled and later referenced returns error

Tags: python, sql, dbt

In Data Build Tool (DBT) - a model that is disabled and later referenced returns error.

I have many steps in my project.
Sometime I'd rather that certain models will be disabled (no need to rerun them now) - like this:

```
{{config(
        materialized='incremental',
        enabled=false
    )}}
```

However, if a model is ref-ed to in another model (like this: `{{ ref("MODEL1") }}` ) , and I choose to disable that model (just for this specific run) it finishes with an error that I have a dependency to a model that is disabled.
I would want it to be able to run it and read from that table as if as it was a source table.

This is a potentially a very complex issue but I am really trying to think of creative solutions.

Eventually my motivation is to be able to run the entire project while dynamically deciding that some models should not be running - and if they are referenced, then I want them to be used as sources and not as a dependency.

Did anyone come across this and managed to find a solution?

I was trying to maybe use some jinja code to deal with each {{ ref("MODEL1") }}, and to determine whether or not that model is enabled - and according to that, set the reference as `{{ ref("MODEL1") }}`
or as `{{ source('SCHEMA_NAME', 'MODEL1') }}`  .

However I'm afraid this path could get very messy..

Comment: You have 2 options. You can either treat the table as a static data seed table and use `source` instead of `ref`. If you have code that builds this table and you only want it built once, you can use a static materialization and keep the model enabled. See my answer to this question for how to implement a static materialization: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77692728/how-protect-dbt-seed-command-from-running-in-production/77694031#77694031

Comment: Just noticed it's incremental indicating maybe you do want to run this periodically but not as frequently. In that case you can define 2 DBT selectors. Tag the model you want ignored and create a one job definition that ignores that tag. Then create a 2nd selector that includes it.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed running sometimes, just not all of the times.
Could you reference to what you mean when you mentioned "tag".
Is this "tagging" done using macro or jinja, or something else?
What do you mean when you say "selector"?
I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with these two.
Any reference would be very appreciated

Comment: I'll post an answer with the selector approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use selectors to decide which models to run on a job execution. In your main project directory (same as `dbt_project.yml`), create a file called `selectors.yml`:

```
selectors:
  - name: my_project_with_tags_ignored
    definition:
      # Run everything except models that are tagged as "dont_run"
      union:
        - method: fqn
          value: "*"
        - exclude:
            - method: tag
              value: dont_run
```

In your model:

```
{{
  config({
    "materialized": 'incremental',
    "unique_key": 'some_unique_key',
    "tags": ["dont_run"],
  })
}}
...
```

To run your job:

```
dbt run --selector my_project_with_tags_ignored
```

When you do want to run the model, either do the standard `dbt run` or create another selector configuration with whatever it is you want included. You can include/exclude whatever combination of tags, model names, paths, etc. Documentation can be found here: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/yaml-selectors

Comment: I know how to 'not run' a specific model.
My problem is not with 'how to not run a model'.
My problem is with the other models that are referencing this model later. Are they going to succeed? Are they going to fail.
So - what is going to happen to another model that is referencing this model that is tagged as 'dont run'?

Comment: You'll need to add `children`/`parent` definitions in the selector. One example configuration is: If the not-run model is the only thing model A depends on, then model A will not run and as such can not error. If model A depends on something else that is run then model A will run.